# Hibernate cannot save the relation between the Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have created 2 entities (Student and Course) with many-to-many relationship, I have created student and course separately, that means I may create student first with no course or course without student.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.school.Student" table="student">
    <id name="id" column="student_id" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="fullName" type="string">
        <column name="full_name" length="40" />
    </property>
    <version name="version" column="VERSION" type="integer" />
    <property name="createdBy" type="string">
        <column name="created_by" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="created_date" length="29" />
    </property>
    <property name="updatedBy" type="string">
        <column name="updated_by" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="updatedDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="updated_date" length="29" />
    </property>

    <set name="course" table="student_course"
        lazy="false" cascade="all" inverse="true">
        <key column="student_id" />
        <many-to-many column="course_id" class="com.school.Course" />
    </set>
        </class>


   <class name="com.school.Course" table="course">
    <id name="id" column="course_id" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="limit" type="int">
        <column name="limit" />
    </property>
    <property name="courseName" type="string">
        <column name="course_name" length="50" />
    </property>
    <version name="version" column="VERSION" type="integer" />
    <property name="createdBy" type="string">
        <column name="created_by" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="created_date" length="29" />
    </property>
    <property name="updatedBy" type="string">
        <column name="updated_by" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="updatedDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="updated_date" length="29" />
    </property>

    <set name="student" table="student_course"
        lazy="false" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="course_id"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many column="student_id" class="com.school.Student" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable, Entity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -546886879998950467L;
private String id;
private int version;
private String createdBy;
private String updatedBy;
private Date createdDate;
private Date updatedDate;
private String fullName;

private Set<Course> course = new HashSet<Course>(0);

public Set<Course> getCourse(){
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(Set<Course> c){
    this.course=c;
}

public boolean isNew() {
    return (getId() == null || getId().isEmpty());
}

public Student() {
}

public int getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}

public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new BigInteger(getId(), 16).hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Student s) {
    return getId().equals(s.getId());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj instanceof Student) {
        Student s = (Student) obj;
        return equals(s);
    }

    return false;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public String getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}

public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public Date getUpdatedDate() {
    return updatedDate;
}

public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
```

}

Course Class:

```
public class Course implements java.io.Serializable, Entity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7827469634033428134L;
private String id;
private int version;
private String createdBy;
private String updatedBy;
private Date createdDate;
private Date updatedDate;
private String courseName;
private int limit;

private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<Student>(0);

public Set<Course> getStudent(){
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Set<Student> s){
    this.student=s;
}

public boolean isNew() {
    return (getId() == null || getId().isEmpty());
}

public Course() {
}

public int getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}

public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new BigInteger(getId(), 16).hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Course c) {
    return getId().equals(c.getId());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj instanceof Course) {
        Course c = (Course) obj;
        return equals(c);
    }

    return false;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public String getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}

public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public Date getUpdatedDate() {
    return updatedDate;
}

public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
    this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public int getLimit() {
    return this.limit;
}

public void setLimit(int l) {
    this.limit = l;
}
```

}

controllor code:

```
        for(int i=0;selectCourse.getChosenDataList()!=null && selectCourse.getChosenDataList().size()<i;i++){
        Course c = (Course)selectCourse.getChosenDataList()get(i);
        student.getCourseList().add(c);
    }

    .....
    ......


    try {
        getStudentService().saveOrUpdate(student);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        MessageUtils.showErrorMessage(e.getMostSpecificCause().toString());
        return;
    }
```

Hibernate show sql:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    student
    (fullName, VERSION, created_by, created_date, updated_by, updated_date) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

It did not generate the insert statement for the table student_course.
do I need to create a projo and dao for student_course relationship and do it after by myself?

I read some online example such as http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-xml-mapping-example/, I think I am doing almost like they do, but they are new object on both side of relationship.

can anyone point me out what did I missed? or really I need to create the relationship by my self each time the new student created or I edit the course set?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go again.

Your association is bidirectional. In a bidirectional association, there is an owner side (here: `Course.student`, which, BTW should be named `students`) and an inverse side (here: `Student.course`, which, BTW, should be named `courses`).

Your code only sets the inverse side of the association, and doesn't set the owner side. Since Hibernate only considers the owner side of the association, it doesn't save the association.

So, you need to call `c.getStudents().add(student)`.

Comment: Hi JB,Thank you, it really save the relation and save me now ;)